# Django Formset to respond to survey/questionnaire

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

In short: I have an app where a user inputs workouts. Before they add exercises to their workout, they must submit a 'readiness' questionnaire with 5-10 questions, rating each low-high. I can't work out how to list ALL ReadinessQuestions in a view, and have the user submit an answer for each of them in a formset.

Models: Model with the question set (ReadinessQuestion), and model that stores readiness_question, rating and the Workout it belongs to (WorkoutReadiness).

Form: I've made a ModelForm into a formset_factory. When I set the 'readiness_question' form field widget to be 'readonly', this makes my form invalid and ignores my 'initial' data

View: I want to create a view where the 5-10 Questions from ReadinessQuestion are in a list, with dropdowns for the Answers.

1. I have set initial data for my form (each different question)
2. the user selects the 'rating' they want for each readiness_question
3. a new Workout is instantiated
4. the WorkoutReadiness is saved, with ForeignKey to the new Workout

How my page it looks now (nearly how I want it to look): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLvB.jpg

The error on submission of form:

`Cannot assign "'Sleep'": "WorkoutReadiness.readiness_question" must be a "ReadinessQuestion" instance.`

The Django documentation is really poor here, `widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})` isn't even on the official Django site. If I don't make the readiness_question 'readonly', the user has dropdowns which they can change (this is undesirable).

```
#models.py
class Workout(models.Model):
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date         = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date}'


class ReadinessQuestion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class WorkoutReadiness(models.Model):
    class Rating(models.IntegerChoices):
        LOWEST  = 1
        LOWER   = 2
        MEDIUM  = 3
        HIGHER  = 4
        HIGHEST = 5

    workout            = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    readiness_question = models.ForeignKey(ReadinessQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rating             = models.IntegerField(choices=Rating.choices)
```

```
#forms.py
class WorkoutReadinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = WorkoutReadiness
        fields = ['readiness_question', 'rating',]
    
    readiness_question = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
    )

WRFormSet = forms.formset_factory(WorkoutReadinessForm, extra=0)
```

```
#views.py
def create_workoutreadiness(request):
    questions = ReadinessQuestion.objects.all()
    
    initial_data = [{'readiness_question':q} for q in questions]
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = WRFormSet(request.POST)
        workout = Workout.objects.create(user=request.user)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                readiness_question = cd.get('readiness_question')
                rating = cd.get('rating')
                w_readiness = WorkoutReadiness(
                    workout=workout,
                    readiness_question=readiness_question,
                    rating=rating
                )
                w_readiness.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('routines:workout_exercise_list', kwargs={'pk':workout.id}))
    else:
        formset = WRFormSet(initial=initial_data)
    
                
    context = {
        'questions':questions,
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'routines/workout_readiness/_form.html', context)
```

ALTERNATIVELY:

I can drop the 'readonly' attr and change the rendering of my HTML. However, this causes formset.is_valid() to be false, as the initial data field is not populated. [screenshot of option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1l3F.jpg)

```
#forms.py
class WorkoutReadinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = WorkoutReadiness
        fields = ['readiness_question', 'rating',]

WRFormSet = forms.formset_factory(WorkoutReadinessForm, extra=0)
```

```
#views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = WRFormSet(request.POST, initial=initial_data) ###CHANGED THIS####
        workout = Workout.objects.create(user=request.user)
        print(formset)
        if formset.is_valid():
```

```
#form.html
<table>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.initial.readiness_question }}</td> 
        <td>{{ form.rating }}</td> 
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</table>
```

ALTERNATIVE #2:

*Theoretically I could have my WorkoutReadiness model as a wider model with the 5-10 questions as columns, and 1 row per Workout. I know this goes against tidy data modelling principles, but I can't see a way around this in Django at the moment. Formsets are limiting my project.*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this (using alternative no.1). I'm not sure it's the *best* way, but it works for now:

1. #models.py - Added `blank=True` to `readiness_question` in the `WorkoutReadiness` model
2. #forms.py - Removed the widget with `attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}` - I don't think Django supports this anymore, it certainly doesn't encourage it

```
class WorkoutReadinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = WorkoutReadiness
        fields = ['readiness_question','rating']

WRFormSet = forms.formset_factory(WorkoutReadinessForm, extra=0)
```

3. #views.py - As well as having the formset populated beforehand with the `initial_data`, I made sure to add it back into each form individually after validating. The `form.cleaned_data.readiness_question` field is `None`, until I replace it with each field in `initial_data`

```
#CBV
class WorkoutReadinessCreateView(CreateView):
    model         = WorkoutReadiness
    fields        = ['readiness_question','rating']
    template_name = 'routines/workout_readiness/_form.html'
    initial_data = [{'readiness_question':q} for q in ReadinessQuestion.objects.all()]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = WRFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():            
            return self.form_valid(formset)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def form_valid(self, formset):
        workout = Workout.objects.create(user=self.request.user)
        for idx, form in enumerate(formset):
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            readiness_question = self.initial_data[idx]['readiness_question']
            rating = cd.get('rating')
            w_readiness = WorkoutReadiness(
                workout=workout,
                readiness_question=readiness_question,
                rating=rating
            )
            w_readiness.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse_lazy(
                'routines:workout_exercise_list', 
                kwargs={'pk':workout.id})
            )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Render initial form"""
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = WRFormSet(
            initial =self.initial_data
        )
        return context

#FBV
def create_workoutreadiness(request):
    questions = ReadinessQuestion.objects.all()
    initial_data = [{'readiness_question':q} for q in questions]
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = WRFormSet(request.POST, initial=initial_data)
        workout = Workout.objects.create(user=request.user)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for idx, form in enumerate(formset):
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                readiness_question = initial_data[idx]['readiness_question']
                rating = cd.get('rating')
                w_readiness = WorkoutReadiness(
                    workout=workout,
                    readiness_question=readiness_question,
                    rating=rating
                )
                w_readiness.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('routines:workout_exercise_list', kwargs={'pk':workout.id}))
    else:
        formset = WRFormSet(initial=initial_data)
          
    context = {
        'questions':questions,
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'routines/workout_readiness/_form.html', context)
```

4. #html/template - I render `form.initial.readiness_question`, which means the user can't edit it in a dropdown

```
<div class="form-group my-5">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <table class="mb-3">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ form.initial.readiness_question }}</td> 
          <td>{{ form.rating }}</td> 
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

5. [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sm7I.jpg) - needs tidying up, but the functionality works